# System of linear equations: using an equation that is already gone?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have this system of equations:
$$x+4y+7z=0$$
$$2x+5y+8z=0$$
$$3x+6y+9z=0$$

my book says the first 2 steps for solving this system is to 1) subtract 2 times the first equation from the second equation to get $-3y-6z=0$ and 2) subtract 3 times the first equation from the last equation to get $-6y-12z=0$.

I don't understand why you can use the first equation twice because by the time we get $-3y-6z=0$, the first equation $x+4y+7z=0$ is already gone. My thinking is that by subtracting 2 times the first equation from the second equation, this turns the equations $x+4y+7z=0$ and $2x+5y+8z=0$ into $-3y-6z=0$. So, we now have an equivalent system that consists of $-3y-6z=0$ and $3x+6y+9z=0$. These two equations are all we can work with now. So how are we able to use the first equation $x+4y+7z=0$ again (by multiplying it by 3 and subtracting it from $3x+6y+9z=0$) if we no longer have the first equation.

Comment: You should probably read up on Gaussian Elimination here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: I think you have some fundamental confusions about systems of linear equations. I'd suggest taking a book and learning it from scratch. It'll make a lot more sense.

Comment: The first equation isn’t “gone.” You’ve only replaced the second equation with a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplets**  way of solving three linear simulteneous equations is to assume one of the variables as $p$, so let $z=p$. Then solve the fist two equations: $x+6y=-7p~~~~(1)$  and  $2x+5y=-8p$ get $y==2p$ and $x=p$. Now put these two values in third equation:

$$3x+6y+9y=0~~~(3) \Rightarrow 3p-12p+9p=0 \Rightarrow 0=0.$$ (I) If you get a true statement like $0=0$ 0r $5=5$. It means the equations have infinitely many solutions. Here, in this example this is the case you maget many sets of $(x,y,z)$ by assigning a values to $p.$

There may be two other cases(not in this example):

(II) If you get a false statement like $6=0$ or $7=8$, this means no solution.

(III) If you get a statement like $2p=10$, then $p$ gets fixed as 5. Then you can determine a unique triplet $(x,y,z)$ which will be the unique solution of your proble.

There are other ways too, but this one is the least expensive!

Answer (score 0):

We can write the following system of equations
\begin{align}
x+4y+7z&=0\\
2x+5y+8z&=0\\
3x+6y+9z&=0\\
\end{align}
as an **augmented** matrix
$$\pmatrix{1 & 4 & 7 &|& 0\\2 & 5 & 8&|& 0\\3 & 6 & 9&|& 0}$$
where the first $3$ columns represent $x,y,z$ respectively.
We perform what are called **elementary row operations** on this matrix in order to find solutions, or possibly determine that there are no solutions. You can read more about these [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) or [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/precalc-matrices/elementary-matrix-row-operations/a/matrix-row-operations) (I did not double check these sources, but you can just open practically any linear algebra text as well).

Solving this system yields
$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1 &|& 0\\0 & 1 & 2&|& 0\\0 & 0 & 0&|& 0}$$
(I will leave the solving as an exercise)
or in equation land
\begin{align}
x-z&=0\\
y+2z&=0\\
z&=z
\end{align}

In this case $z$ is a **free variable**, meaning our results for $x$ and $y$ depend on our choice of $z$, and we have infinitely many solutions $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: How is there infinitely many solutions if the point $(1,1,2)$ doesn't satisfy all 3 equations?

Comment: @user532874 We first pick $z$ which determines our values for $x$ and $y$. In your example, $z=2$, and so from our equations $x-2=0 \to x=2$ and $y+2(2)=0 \to y=-4$, and so we obtain $(2,-4,2)$, which is a solution. The infinitely many solutions comes from having infinitely many choices for $z$.

Comment: What would the set of solutions look like graphically then? A plane?

Comment: I graphed $x-z=0$ and $y+2z=0$ on geogebra and they are both planes but I tried graphing $z=z$ and I get nothing.

Comment: Whenever there are infinitely many solutions in general, what does the set of solutions look like visually? Is there a general rule. I.e. is the set of solutions always either a line or a plane or 3D space?

Comment: @user532874 In this case, our solution set is the intersection of the two planes (a line in 3D) as seen in your plot on Geogebra. I believe this is from the fact that our system is really a system of 2 equations with 3 unknowns. Check out this alternate wiki source https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations . You should probably crack open a Linear Algebra text and work through the first couple of chapters... Strang is a popular choice along with Strang's MIT OpenCourseWare for some visual aid.